# Simple Nginx rewrite resulting in 404

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to setup a simple rewrite rule on Nginx and it keeps returning a 404, regardless of what I do:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name site.com;
    access_log off;



    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            rewrite ^/user/(.*)$ /user.php?id=$1 last;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm overlooking here?

Note:

- It's a HTTPS-enabled site, configured with Cert Bot.
- Non-HTTPS is forced to HTTPS.
- It's a new server that I installed using Digital Ocean's LEMP product on Market Place.

The rewrite rule is:

```
rewrite ^/user/(.*)$ /user.php?id=$1 last;
```

Which should result in site.com/user/abc

But it keeps throwing a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I messed up, big time. Realized that the config above is only for port 80. i.e. Plain HTTP. I didn't realize that certbot placed the HTTPS config at the end of the digitalocean config file in sites-available.

Stupid me.